# Catkin_make failed to build opencv

Tags: opencv, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,

I want to compile a package (https://github.com/mjshiggins/ros-examples) with the catkin_make command from the catkin_ws folder, but it seems that the OpenCV header file is depreceated or not installed. I'm sure, that I install all OpenCV dependencies.

```
    /home/pkatsoulakos/catkin_ws/src/ros-examples-master/src/lidar/src/lidar_node.cpp:20:10: fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
   20 | #include <opencv/cv.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [ros-examples-master/src/lidar/CMakeFiles/lidar_node.dir/build.make:63: ros-examples-master/src/lidar/CMakeFiles/lidar_node.dir/src/lidar_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1373: ros-examples-master/src/lidar/CMakeFiles/lidar_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398357/catkin_make-failed-to-build-opencv/) by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2022-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-04-01**:
Have you installed apt package `libopencv-dev`?

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-01**:
yes it's already installed. I copy the `src` folder with the 3 folders: `fusion lidar radar` into my personal workspace and execute catkin_make from the catkin_ws folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

for everyone who is interested i found the fault. The header file is depreceated and must be changed:

```
opencv/cv.h -> opencv2/core.hpp
opencv/highgui -> opencv2/highgui.hpp
+ add the header: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h
```

hope this helps anybody, if he stucked with this message.

---

Originally posted by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) with karma: 28 on 2022-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0